# How do I generate sourcemaps for Uglified files using Grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, source-maps, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-browserify

I have a Grunt project that uses both Browserify and Uglify. Here are the core bits of it:

```
browserify: {
  myapp: {
    options: {
      transform: ['babelify'],
      browserifyOptions: {
        debug: true
      },
    },
    src: 'src/index.js',
    dest: 'build/myapp.js'
  }
},

uglify: {
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    banner: bannerContent
  },
  target: {
    src: 'build/myapp.js',
    dest: 'build/myapp.min.js'
  }
},
```

It seems to generate a `myapp.min.js.map` file but it no longer has the raw sources in the source-map that existed prior to the Browserification.

Here's what the resultant source-map file contains:

```
{
  "version":3,
  "sources":[
    "myapp.js"
  ],
  "names":[
    ...
    ...
    ...
  ],
  "mappings":".........",
  "file":"myapp.min.js"
}
```

I've tried using the `uglifyify` transform for Browserify but that does not seem to generate as small files as the Uglify task.

I've also bumped all my dependencies to the latest but I haven't been able to resolve this issue.

Comment: `grunt-browserify` doesn't create external src map file - see [here](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify/issues/307). Try: **1)** Using [grunt-extract-sourcemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-extract-sourcemap) to read inline src maps from `myapp.js` and create external src map file _(note: run this task after your current browserify task and before uglify task)_. **2)** Set [`sourceMapIn`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/33724cd1008a02f865921e0a2c8f748461c84d43/docs/uglify-options.md#sourcemapin) option in `uglify` task to use src map created at step 1.

Comment: @RobC When the script gets minified with the uglify step, will the resultant script file still have a correct mappings to the source map file? If I've understood correctly, the Unglify step only minifies the JS file but does not change the source-map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grunt-contrib-uglify` has a [`sourceMapIn`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/33724cd1008a02f865921e0a2c8f748461c84d43/docs/uglify-options.md#sourcemapin) option that allows you to specify the location of an input source map file from an earlier compilation - which in your scenario is the `browserify` task.

However, whilst setting `browserifyOptions: { debug: true }` in your `browserify` task does generate an inline source map in the resultant `.js` file (i.e. in `build/myapp.js`), the crux of the problem is twofold:

1. We don't have an external source map file that we can configure the `sourceMapIn` option of the subsequent `grunt-contrib-uglify` task to utilize.
2. `grunt-browserify` doesn't provide a feature to create an external `.map` file, it only creates them inline (see [here](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify/issues/307))

To address the aforementioned issue consider utilizing [grunt-extract-sourcemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-extract-sourcemap) to extract the inline source map from `build/myapp.js` (i.e. from the output file generated by your `browserify` task) after it has been produced.

**Gruntfile.js**

The following gist shows how your *Gruntfile.js* should be configured:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({

      browserify: {
        myapp: {
          options: {
            transform: ['babelify'],
            browserifyOptions: {
              debug: true
            },
          },
          src: 'src/index.js',
          dest: 'build/myapp.js'
        }
      },

      extract_sourcemap: {
        myapp: {
          files: {
            'build': ['build/myapp.js']
          }
        }
      },

      uglify: {
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapIn: 'build/myapp.js.map'
        },
        target: {
          src: 'build/myapp.js',
          dest: 'build/myapp.min.js'
        }
      }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-extract-sourcemap');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Note the order of the tasks in your task list is important.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserify', 'extract_sourcemap', 'uglify']);
};
```

**Explanation**

1. First the `browserify` task is invoked which outputs a new file (i.e. `build/myapp.js`) containing your bundled JavaScript and an *"inlined"* source map info. If you were to inspect the content of `build/myapp.js` at this stage it includes something like the following at the end:

   ```js
   //# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64, ...
   ```
2. Next the `extract_sourcemap` task is invoked. This essentially extracts the *"inlined"* source map info from `build/myapp.js` and writes it to a new file named `myapp.js.map` which is saved in your `build` directory.

   The original *"inlined"* source map info in `build/myapp.js` is replaced with a link to the newly generated source map file, i.e. `myapp.js.map`. If you inspect the content of `build/myapp.js` you'll now notice the following at the end of the file instead:

   ```js
   //# sourceMappingURL=myapp.js.map
   ```
3. Lastly the `uglify` task is invoked. Notice how its `sourceMapIn` option is configured to read `build/myapp.js.map`, i.e the source map file we generated at step 2.

   This task creates your desired `build/myapp.min.js` file containing; your minified JS, and a link to a newly generated source map file `build/myapp.min.js.map`.

**Note** The final resultant file (i.e. `build/myapp.min.js`) now correctly maps back to the original `src/index.js` file and any file(s) that `index.js` itself may have `import`'ed or `require()`'d

Comment: This seems to be removing the sources from the map file. The intermediate file has it but the resultant doesn't. I've added `sourceMapIncludeSources: true` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions Rob?

Comment: Apparently it has changed: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/master/docs/uglify-options.md#sourcemapincludesources

Comment: Interestingly I get  `"sources": [ .... ]` listed in the resultant `build/myapp.min.js.map` file using config shown in my answer. What happens If you add  `sourceMap: { includeSources: true }` to your `uglify` tasks `options` object? Failing that perhaps try utilizing earlier version of _grunt-contrib-uglify_.

Comment: No luck with sourceMap: { includeSources: true }.  @RobC - Do you know which version of grunt-contrib-uglify you used?

Comment: Rolling back to ^2.0.0 of grunt-contrib-uglify did not work either.  I get an error of 
Warning: Uglification failed.
Unable to read "dist/index.js.map" file (Error code: ENOENT)..